# Apex test class insert KML data into FSL__Polygon__c field FSL_KML__c

Tags: apex, xml

I am trying to insert a single polygon into FSL__Polygon__c object for testing. When I run this I get KML data structure is invalid. This is a direct pull from an existing entry.

How can I insert this record in a test class?

```js
FSL__Polygon__c myPolygon = new FSL__Polygon__c(
                OwnerId = '0052G000009Pqt9QAC'
                ,Name = 'Central SSS'
                ,FSL__Color__c = '#5679C0'
                ,FSL__KML__c =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> '+
                '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">'+
                '<Style id="CentralSSSStyle">'+
                '<LineStyle>'+
                '<width>1</width>'+
                '</LineStyle>'+
                '<PolyStyle>'+
                '<color>80C07956</color>'+
                '</PolyStyle>'+
                '</Style>'+
                '<Placemark>'+
                '<name>CentralSSS</name>'+
                '<styleUrl>#CentralSSSStyle</styleUrl>'+
                '<Polygon>'+
                '<outerBoundaryIs>'+
                '<LinearRing>'+
                '<coordinates>-89.02172505348693,47.81952924639332,0'+
                '-84.18774067848693,48.01097620848099,0'+
                '-84.89086567848693,46.22441984873406,0'+
                '-88.34057270973693,45.91190522847453,0'+
                '-88.90087544411193,47.53103006689299,0'+
                '-89.30736958473693,47.77524856801052,0'+
                '-89.02172505348693,47.81952924639332,0'+
                '</coordinates>'+
                '</LinearRing>'+
                '</outerBoundaryIs>'+
                '</Polygon>'+
                '</Placemark>'+
                '</kml>'
                ,FSL__Service_Territory__c = '0Hh2G000000006iSAA'
                ,FSL__Ma_La__c = 48.01097620848099
                ,FSL__Ma_Lo__c = -84.18774067848693
                ,FSL__Mi_La__c = 45.91190522847453
                ,FSL__Mi_Lo__c = -89.30736958473693
        );
        insert myPolygon;
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: I extracted the xml, formatted it and it seems valid xml. Have you tried to validate it using any online kml validator? May be there is some semantic issue with kml data.

Comment: Here is the full error I got when I tried to run this code. System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Polygon KML data structure is invalid: []

AnonymousBlock: line 41, column 1